# Had a 1-day virtual onsite (late in application process) and spoke to 9 people across 3 interviews. Do I send follow-up thank you emails to everyone?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, email-etiquette

The most amount of people I've spoken to in a day, for the same job application, has been four. Nine people is...a lot. Although it was great to meet the people I could work with, the prospect of sending nine separate emails is bothering me. At the risk of using the same template (or a few templates) I don't want them to say, "Hey @Bodrov sent me that same email!"

Should I email everyone, or just the person I'd be working directly under?

Comment: Do you even have all of their emails to begin with?

Comment: @DarkCygnus The emails I've seen from three people are First.Last@company.com , so I imagine the others are the same.

Comment: @Bodrov You cannot assume that. Bob Smith will be confused.

Comment: You can really only get opinions on this:  I'd say "No" personally

Answer (score 6):

The answer may depend on the country and the industry you are working in.

I am working in the IT industry in the US.

While I have nothing against "**sending thank-you notes after the interviews**" as it may be a good way to widen your contacts and networking, I have always chosen not to do that.

I usually thank the interviewers directly at the end of the interview. To me that is nice, professional, and diplomatic enough. I believe there is no need to send "thank-you" notes after the interview as it may be redundant.

Plus, the interviewers may be too busy and don't have time to read these "thank-you" notes. Some of them may find it unpleasant that you send them extra notes and communications while they are busy. Overall, most interviewers simply prefer that you patiently wait for their official decision on whether they would hire you.

(*Now, if you have not heard from the interviewers 3 weeks after the interview, then you can send them an email asking them about their decision if you want to. But, that is a different topic)*.

**Note**: Again, however, other countries and industries may have different preferences about sending "thank-you" notes after the interview.

If possible, would you please mention the country and industry you are in ?

Comment: Yes to this answer - it's definitely cultural. I've heard "thank you" e-mails are a thing in the US, but elsewhere (for example the UK) they could come across as an attempt to influence the interviewers (which, of course, they are), or as just plain weird.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 I'm in the US and work in software engineering.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, I only send “thank you” emails if something came up in the conversation that would be worth following up on. For example:

> Great meeting you earlier! Here’s some more info about that technique I mentioned in case you’re interested.

Sending a generic “thank you” email to ten people to me seems excessive and unnecessary. It’s one of those silly things career coaches tell you to do that no one in the real world actually  cares about.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I email everyone, or just the person I'd be working directly under?

Yeah, 9 emails seems like too many to send them separately and with a template. But at the end **it's a matter of preference**.

Alternatives I suggest:

- Send a single email and include all 9 people as recipients, thanking them all in general, expressing your interest in the company, etc.. This implies that you have all of their emails.
- Send your thank-you email to the person you have been more in contact with, that is your prospect supervisor or the recruiter, depending on your situation. In this email, write what you have to thank and say, and include or mention these other persons that were part of the process, extending your wishes to them.

Personally, I would go for the second option, as the idea of sending 9 separate mails or even include 9 separate individuals in a single mail for a thank-you also bothers me (like, in the sense erroneously appearing too intense/desperate in the eyes of these people, if they all were to receive a thank you).

Answer (score 2):

In a comment you state that you're going to try to figure out the email addresses of the people that interviewed you, and directly email them.

No, you should not do this.

You should have thanked them during the interview. You should thank your primary contact and ask them to pass on your thanks to those involved.

Answer (score 0):

9 people is fine, because you actually interacted with them and spoke to all of them.

If you somehow found their departmental email, then emails all their departments, then that's "too much".